# send snowflake runtime errors to Amazon Notification Service(SNS)

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, amazon-sns

I want to listen to the errors when some script are executed in snowflake and send them to the Amazon Notification Service(SNS), anyone can guide me please how to implement that in snowflake? thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could create an external function that sends the SNS message:

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/external-functions-introduction.html
https://mkdev.me/en/posts/how-to-send-sms-messages-with-aws-lambda-sns-and-python-3

Then in Snowflake you could run:

select external_function('error message');

Then your external function would send 'error message' as an SNS message.

Comment: One another solution I can think of is Step function. You can schedule your task and one of the task can be Notify error. Then when error occurs which call this step and sends a SNS notification. This way you will be notified.

Comment: Thank you @cmconner156 for your answer, that would help a lot, but the missing part is how can I catch the error when it is happening? is using stored procedure a good way to do that?
https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/stored-procedures-usage.html